# Why does POSIXct command return NA in R?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I'm trying to change a character variable to date-time  using the `POSIXct` command, but it's changing the entire vector to NA, no matter how I write the code. Can you help me?

I have tried the following

```r
Annual_Trips$started_at <- as.POSIXct(Annual_Trips$started_at,
                             format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
Annual_Trips$started_at <- as.POSIXct(Annual_Trips$started_at, 
                             "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also I'm confused about how to use time zones. Do i use the time zone of my location, or location of the data collected?

This is what the dataframe looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFzYU.png)

Comment: Please show us a row or two of your data.

Comment: I've attached an image of  it

Comment: If I may: We asked for the data, not an _image_ of the data.  Subset two or three rows, call `dput()` on that, paste that _as R code we can run_ in order to help you.

Comment: It's much nicer to add data as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture of a table. If you use the `dput` command you can create a small copy/pasteable version of your data in valid R syntax, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:5, 1:4])` for the first 5 rows and first 4 columns. (Choose a relevant subset to share.) Squinting at your picture, I see `-` characters not `/` characters in your input, so your `format` string also needs to use `-`, not `/`.

Comment: Thank you, @GregorThomas, you are absolutely right. I dont know how i missed using the wrong divider in the dates. I used - and it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: You're quite welcome. Date format strings are one of those things that are very hard before you see it, and very easy after you see it.